# Can not use method void java.sql.CallableStatement.setObject(String parameterName, Object x, int targetSqlType)

Tags: sql, package, prepared-statement, procedure, callable-statement

This is my Procedure code:
Specification:

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_NALD AS 
    PROCEDURE PROC_KETQUA(res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ,maMH STRING); 
END PKG_NALD;
```

Body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_NALD AS

  PROCEDURE PROC_KETQUA(res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ,maMH STRING) AS
  BEGIN
       OPEN res FOR
     select MA_MH as maMH123, TEN_MH as tenMH, TIN_CHI as tinChi, KHOA as khoa from nald_mon_hoc where upper(ma_mh) = upper(maMH);
  END PROC_KETQUA;

END PKG_NALD;
```

And this's my code in order to call Procedure through CallableStatement:

```
String sqlQuery = "call PKG_NALD.PROC_KETQUA(?, :maMH)";
Connection connection = ((SessionImpl)session).connection();
CallableStatement callable = connection.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
callable.setObject (2, "COSC1310", Types.VARCHAR); // This method belongs to java.sql.PreparedStatement
callable.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callable.execute();
```

The program can run correctly. However, if I replace callable.setObject (2, "COSC1310", Types.VARCHAR) with

```
callable.setObject("maMH", "COSC1310", Types.VARCHAR); // This method belongs to java.sql.CallableStatement
```

I received the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.setNamedParameters(OracleSql.java:196)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4708)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
    at com.mkyong.util.QueryUtil.getListFromPackage(QueryUtil.java:71)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:35)
```

Despite of [the document here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29), something went wrong. What should I do ?

Comment: I am not sure if this has been fixed, but for a long time the JDBC driver for Oracle would not support named parameters. You could have them in your query, but they would just be replaced by "?" and you had to bind them by index. Maybe that's still the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
String sqlQuery = "call PKG_NALD.PROC_KETQUA(?, :maMH)";
```

To this

```
String sqlQuery = "call PKG_NALD.PROC_KETQUA(?, ?)";
```

Comment: According to your advice, I received that error:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Attempt to set a parameter name that does not occur in the SQL: maMH
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.addNamedPara(OracleCallableStatement.java:6626)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:5879)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.setObject(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:210)
 at com.mkyong.util.QueryUtil.getListFromPackage(QueryUtil.java:69)
 at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:35)

Comment: ok, the callable statement musn't have access to the metadata relating to the procedure, meaning it doesn't recognise the name of the parameter. This means you are probably restricted to using the positional index to choose the parameter to set based on your approach.